# PHP CURL and Cache of JSON Result

Tags: php, json, curl, caching

i want cache from json result from a curl but getting error 
function grabe($url,$dir,$rename,$time='0',$format='json') {

```
$tmp_dir = 'cache';
$dir=$tmp_dir.$dir;
$rename=md5($rename);
$file=$dir.'/'.$rename.'.'.$format;
if(!is_dir($dir)) {mkdir($dir, 0755);}
$cachetime=(60*$time);


if (file_exists($file) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($file))
{
    $rawdata=file_get_contents($file);
    return $rawdata;
}else
{
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$uaa = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: $uaa");
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
if($rawdata){
$fp = fopen("$file",'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata); 
fclose($fp);     
return $rawdata;
   } 

}}
```

eror saying output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function grabe(), 1 passed in /home/hdmoviewap/public_html/index.php on line 182 and at least 3 expected in /home/hdmoviewap/public_html/core/init.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/hdmoviewap/public_html/index.php(182): grabe('https://www.goo...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/hdmoviewap/public_html/core/init.php on line 3
```

my 182 line index.php blew

```
$grab=grabe('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='.$key.'&part=snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=20&q=Latest+Bollywood+Video&type=video');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are calling the grabe function only with an url but without values for the **dir** and **rename** parameters.

So, you need something like:

```
$grab=grabe('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='.$key.'&part=snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=20&q=Latest+Bollywood+Video&type=video', 'dir', $rename);
```

Comment: how to fix it dear?

Comment: Just pass two more params. You are doing $grab = grabe(url) and you must execute $grab = grabe(url, 'directory', 'rename')

Comment: where in 182 line in index.php ?

Comment: Yes, add the two parameters at the end of the method